# HTML5 Doctype in IE7 breaking Jquery Dropdown Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, doctype

One of my websites throws up an error about the javascript not being defined when I view it in IE7.

After a bit of research, I think its something to do with the Doctype I am using, as I am using the HTML5 Boilerplate. This shouldnt cause a problem though right?

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how to fix it? The website is: http://njbuildingandmaintenance.com

And here is the menu script I am using (the error isnt replicated on this page...) http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/ddlevelsmenu/

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your file "script.js", there's a stray comma at the end of an object literal.

```
$(window).load(function() {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
         animation: "fade",
         slideshow: true,                //Should the slider animate automatically by default? (true/false)
         slideshowSpeed: 7000,           //Set the speed of the slideshow cycling, in milliseconds
         animationDuration: 600,
         keyboardNav: true,              //Allow for keyboard navigation using left/right keys (true/false)
         touchSwipe: true,  // <---- HERE IS THE ERROR
        });
    });
```

Get rid of that comma.

Comment: Is that something specific to IE?  I only ask because I tend to develop for Chrome & Firefox and make a habit of leaving a trailing , so I don't forget to do it later if I add more data.

Comment: Yes, it's specific to IE prior to IE8.  Stray commas make IE7 and earlier very angry :-)

Comment: Learn to use IE7's developer tools. They're horrible, but they would have told you about this error.

Comment: @maxedison or use IE8 in IE7 mode, which isn't 100% bug-for-bug the same as real IE7 but in this case it catches it. The IE8 developer tools are considerably better.

Comment: awesome! Works a treat. Cheers guys